# php javascript drag and drop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drag-and-drop

Hey guys i got a problem with my DnD solution.

It works well as long as i dont write something into my textarea.
 That means if the page is loading data from MySQL into the Area it works, if i try to put write something in it by my self it doesnt.
Does someone know how i can fix this? so that i can write into my Area and still drop something in there?
Below the important part of the Script if you need more to see why it is not working, let me know.
Got the Code for it from: 
http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=drag-drop-custom

Generating dragabele Image preview:

```
$dir = "../../images";
$handle=opendir ($dir);
while (($file = readdir ($handle)) !== false) {
if ( filetype( $dir.'/'.$file) == "file" 
    AND ((substr( $file, -4) == ".jpg")
    || (substr( $file, -4) == ".png")
    || (substr( $file, -4) == ".gif"))){
echo " <div id='".$file."' style='float: left; width:120px; height:125px;  border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:black;'>
<img  src=".$dir."/".$file." width=110 style='height: 110px;'>
$file
</div>";
echo " <script type='text/javascript'>
dragDropObj.addSource('".$file."',true);
</script>";
}
}
closedir($handle);
```

Now im dropping them into a textarea with the following Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function dropImg1(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y){
            var html = document.getElementById('text_kurz').innerHTML;
            if(html.length>0)html = html + ' ';
            html = html + '<img src="/images/' + idOfDraggedItem+'">';
            document.getElementById('text_kurz').innerHTML = html;
        }
        function dropImg2(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y){
            var html = document.getElementById('text_lang').innerHTML;
            if(html.length>0)html = html + ' ';
            html = html + '<img src="/images/' + idOfDraggedItem+'">';
            document.getElementById('text_lang').innerHTML = html;
        }
        function dropImg3(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y){
            var html = document.getElementById('nachwort').innerHTML;
            if(html.length>0)html = html + ' ';
            html = html + '<img src="/images/' + idOfDraggedItem+'">';
            document.getElementById('nachwort').innerHTML = html;
        }

        var dragDropObj = new DHTMLgoodies_dragDrop();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Guys ive got the solution... its that simple that i didnt even thought about that...

its just:

```
.innerHTML
```

to

```
.value
```

Thanks anyway ;)
Hope i could help out someone having the same problem